# Making php only retrieve/echo line certain lines

Tags: php, html

Im trying to make it so my php code will only get the lines I want and only echo them

This is my current code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['resolve'])){
$api = "http://ip-api.com/line/";
if(strlen($_POST['name'])==0){
echo "fill in all fields!";
} else {
echo htmlentities($_POST['name'])."'s IP: ".htmlentities(file_get_contents($api.$_POST['name']));
}
}
?>
```

If you go to "http://ip-api.com/line/58.7.81.182" for example I only want it to echo lines 2,5,6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use their PHP api:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['resolve'])){
        $api = "http://ip-api.com/php/";
        if(strlen($_POST['name'])==0){
            echo "fill in all fields!";
        } else {
            // assuming $_POST['resolve'] has an IP
            $response = file_get_contents($api.$_POST['resolve']); 
            $array = unserialize($response);
            echo $array['regionName']; // or whatever value you want
         }
    }
```

Their PHP api returns a serialized response, so you just need to call unserialize() in order to have a simple to use array

Answer (score 0):

You can store the contents in an array with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) as follows

```
$content = htmlentities(file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/line/58.7.81.182"));
$contentArr = explode("\n",$content);
```

Then access the desired value with `lineNum - 1` since the array index is zero-based.

```
$lineNum = 2;
echo $contentArr[$lineNum-1];
$lineNum = 5;
echo $contentArr[$lineNum-1];
$lineNum = 6;
echo $contentArr[$lineNum-1];
```

**Full code**

```
$content = htmlentities(file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/line/58.7.81.182"));
$contentArr = explode("\n",$content);
$lineNum = 2;
echo $contentArr[$lineNum-1];
$lineNum = 5;
echo $contentArr[$lineNum-1];
$lineNum = 6;
echo $contentArr[$lineNum-1];
```